# C++ Why Direct3D11 Renders Black Scene When Switching Adapter?

Tags: c++, rendering, direct2d, direct3d11

I made a texting program with Direct3D11 which allow me both 2D and 3D drawing. I used rastertek.com sample to get 3D scene faster. Then I added my D2D class and passed it trough DXGI without creating 2D device. That was working properly. However, I realized that my PC has no NVIDIA driver so that is why I was using INTEL IGraphics by default. I installed NVIDIA drivers. Reset, switched my preferred video processor to NVIDIA from control panel. Then, debug and I got a black screen. I am not an experienced person. That looks like solving it will be impossible for me. What can I do to fix it ?

I ADDED FULL PROJECT FILE:
    https://easyupload.io/3fc087

THIS IS WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE ON INTEL GRAPHICS:[image]

d3dclass.cpp if needed

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Filename: d3dclass.cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "d3dclass.h"
#include <Windows.h>

D3DClass::D3DClass()
{
    m_swapChain = 0;
    m_device = 0;
    m_deviceContext = 0;
    m_renderTargetView = 0;
    m_depthStencilBuffer = 0;
    m_depthStencilState = 0;
    m_depthStencilView = 0;
    m_rasterState = 0;
}

D3DClass::D3DClass(const D3DClass& other)
{
}

D3DClass::~D3DClass()
{
}

bool D3DClass::Initialize(int screenWidth, int screenHeight, bool vsync, HWND hwnd, bool fullscreen,
    float screenDepth, float screenNear)
{
    HRESULT result;
    IDXGIFactory* factory;
    IDXGIAdapter* adapter;
    IDXGIOutput* adapterOutput;
    unsigned int numModes, i, numerator, denominator;
    size_t stringLength;
    DXGI_MODE_DESC* displayModeList;
    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC adapterDesc;
    int error;
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
    ID3D11Texture2D* backBufferPtr;

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthBufferDesc;
    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthStencilDesc;
    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilViewDesc;
    D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rasterDesc;
    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    float fieldOfView, screenAspect;


    // Store the vsync setting.
    m_vsync_enabled = vsync;

    // Create a DirectX graphics interface factory.
    result = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)&factory);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Use the factory to create an adapter for the primary graphics interface (video card).
    result = factory->EnumAdapters(0, &adapter);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Enumerate the primary adapter output (monitor).
    result = adapter->EnumOutputs(0, &adapterOutput);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Get the number of modes that fit the DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM display format for the adapter output (monitor).
    result = adapterOutput->GetDisplayModeList(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, DXGI_ENUM_MODES_INTERLACED, &numModes, NULL);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Create a list to hold all the possible display modes for this monitor/video card combination.
    displayModeList = new DXGI_MODE_DESC[numModes];
    if (!displayModeList)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Now fill the display mode list structures.
    result = adapterOutput->GetDisplayModeList(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, DXGI_ENUM_MODES_INTERLACED, &numModes, displayModeList);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Now go through all the display modes and find the one that matches the screen width and height.
    // When a match is found store the numerator and denominator of the refresh rate for that monitor.
    for (i = 0; i<numModes; i++)
    {
        if (displayModeList[i].Width == (unsigned int)screenWidth)
        {
            if (displayModeList[i].Height == (unsigned int)screenHeight)
            {
                numerator = displayModeList[i].RefreshRate.Numerator;
                denominator = displayModeList[i].RefreshRate.Denominator;
            }
        }
    }

    // Get the adapter (video card) description.
    result = adapter->GetDesc(&adapterDesc);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Store the dedicated video card memory in megabytes.
    m_videoCardMemory = (int)(adapterDesc.DedicatedVideoMemory / 1024 / 1024);

    // Convert the name of the video card to a character array and store it.
    error = wcstombs_s(&stringLength, m_videoCardDescription, 128, adapterDesc.Description, 128);
    error = wcstombs_s(&stringLength, m_videoCardDescription, 128, adapterDesc.Description, 128);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Release the display mode list.
    delete[] displayModeList;
    displayModeList = 0;

    // Release the adapter output.
    adapterOutput->Release();
    adapterOutput = 0;

    // Release the adapter.
    adapter->Release();
    adapter = 0;

    // Release the factory.
    factory->Release();
    factory = 0;

    // Initialize the swap chain description.
    ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(swapChainDesc));

    // Set to a single back buffer.
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;

    // Set the width and height of the back buffer.
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = screenWidth;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = screenHeight;

    // Set regular 32-bit surface for the back buffer.
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;

    // Set the refresh rate of the back buffer.
    if (m_vsync_enabled)
    {
        swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = numerator;
        swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = denominator;
    }
    else
    {
        swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 0;
        swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    }

    // Set the usage of the back buffer.
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;

    // Set the handle for the window to render to.
    swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hwnd;

    // Turn multisampling off.
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

    // Set to full screen or windowed mode.
    if (fullscreen)
    {
        swapChainDesc.Windowed = false;
    }
    else
    {
        swapChainDesc.Windowed = true;
    }

    // Set the scan line ordering and scaling to unspecified.
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

    // Discard the back buffer contents after presenting.
    swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;

    // Don't set the advanced flags.
    swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;

    // Set the feature level to DirectX 11.
    featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;

    // Create the swap chain, Direct3D device, and Direct3D device context.
    result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT, &featureLevel, 1,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &m_swapChain, &m_device, NULL, &m_deviceContext);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Get the pointer to the back buffer.
    result = m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&backBufferPtr);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Create the render target view with the back buffer pointer.
    result = m_device->CreateRenderTargetView(backBufferPtr, NULL, &m_renderTargetView);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Release pointer to the back buffer as we no longer need it.
    backBufferPtr->Release();
    backBufferPtr = 0;

    // Initialize the description of the depth buffer.
    ZeroMemory(&depthBufferDesc, sizeof(depthBufferDesc));

    // Set up the description of the depth buffer.
    depthBufferDesc.Width = screenWidth;
    depthBufferDesc.Height = screenHeight;
    depthBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    depthBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    depthBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    depthBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    depthBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    depthBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    // Create the texture for the depth buffer using the filled out description.
    result = m_device->CreateTexture2D(&depthBufferDesc, NULL, &m_depthStencilBuffer);

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Initialize the description of the stencil state.
    ZeroMemory(&depthStencilDesc, sizeof(depthStencilDesc));

    // Set up the description of the stencil state.
    depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = true;
    depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
    depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;

    depthStencilDesc.StencilEnable = true;
    depthStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
    depthStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

    // Stencil operations if pixel is front-facing.
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

    // Stencil operations if pixel is back-facing.
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

    // Create the depth stencil state.
    result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilDesc, &m_depthStencilState);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Set the depth stencil state.
    m_deviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_depthStencilState, 1);

    // Initialize the depth stencil view.
    ZeroMemory(&depthStencilViewDesc, sizeof(depthStencilViewDesc));

    // Set up the depth stencil view description.
    depthStencilViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    depthStencilViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    depthStencilViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

    // Create the depth stencil view.
    result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilBuffer, &depthStencilViewDesc, &m_depthStencilView);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Bind the render target view and depth stencil buffer to the output render pipeline.
    m_deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_renderTargetView, m_depthStencilView);

    // create the D2D factory

    // Setup the raster description which will determine how and what polygons will be drawn.
    rasterDesc.AntialiasedLineEnable = true;
    rasterDesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_BACK;
    rasterDesc.DepthBias = 0;
    rasterDesc.DepthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
    rasterDesc.DepthClipEnable = true;
    rasterDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
    rasterDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
    rasterDesc.MultisampleEnable = false;
    rasterDesc.ScissorEnable = false;
    rasterDesc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0.0f;

    // Create the rasterizer state from the description we just filled out.
    result = m_device->CreateRasterizerState(&rasterDesc, &m_rasterState);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Now set the rasterizer state.
    m_deviceContext->RSSetState(m_rasterState);

    // Setup the viewport for rendering.
    viewport.Width = (float)screenWidth;
    viewport.Height = (float)screenHeight;
    viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    viewport.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0.0f;

    // Create the viewport.
    m_deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    // Setup the projection matrix.
    fieldOfView = 3.141592654f / 4.0f;
    screenAspect = (float)screenWidth / (float)screenHeight;

    // Create the projection matrix for 3D rendering.
    m_projectionMatrix = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(fieldOfView, screenAspect, screenNear, screenDepth);

    // Initialize the world matrix to the identity matrix.
    m_worldMatrix = XMMatrixIdentity();

    // Create an orthographic projection matrix for 2D rendering.
    m_orthoMatrix = XMMatrixOrthographicLH((float)screenWidth, (float)screenHeight, screenNear, screenDepth);

    return true;
}

void D3DClass::Shutdown()
{
    // Before shutting down set to windowed mode or when you release the swap chain it will throw an exception.
    if (m_swapChain)
    {
        m_swapChain->SetFullscreenState(false, NULL);
    }

    if (m_rasterState)
    {
        m_rasterState->Release();
        m_rasterState = 0;
    }

    if (m_depthStencilView)
    {
        m_depthStencilView->Release();
        m_depthStencilView = 0;
    }

    if (m_depthStencilState)
    {
        m_depthStencilState->Release();
        m_depthStencilState = 0;
    }

    if (m_depthStencilBuffer)
    {
        m_depthStencilBuffer->Release();
        m_depthStencilBuffer = 0;
    }

    if (m_renderTargetView)
    {
        m_renderTargetView->Release();
        m_renderTargetView = 0;
    }

    if (m_deviceContext)
    {
        m_deviceContext->Release();
        m_deviceContext = 0;
    }

    if (m_device)
    {
        m_device->Release();
        m_device = 0;
    }

    if (m_swapChain)
    {
        m_swapChain->Release();
        m_swapChain = 0;
    }

    return;
}


void D3DClass::BeginScene(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha)
{
    float color[4];


    // Setup the color to clear the buffer to.
    color[0] = red;
    color[1] = green;
    color[2] = blue;
    color[3] = alpha;

    // Clear the back buffer.

    m_deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(m_renderTargetView, color);

    // Clear the depth buffer.
    m_deviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);

    return;
}


void D3DClass::ClearDepthStencilView() {
    m_deviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
}

void D3DClass::EndScene()
{
    // Present the back buffer to the screen since rendering is complete.
    if (m_vsync_enabled)
    {
        // Lock to screen refresh rate.
        m_swapChain->Present(1, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        // Present as fast as possible.
        m_swapChain->Present(0, 0);
    }

    return;
}


ID3D11Device* D3DClass::GetDevice()
{
    return m_device;
}


ID3D11DeviceContext* D3DClass::GetDeviceContext()
{
    return m_deviceContext;
}


void D3DClass::GetProjectionMatrix(XMMATRIX& projectionMatrix)
{
    projectionMatrix = m_projectionMatrix;
    return;
}


void D3DClass::GetWorldMatrix(XMMATRIX& worldMatrix)
{
    worldMatrix = m_worldMatrix;
    return;
}


void D3DClass::GetOrthoMatrix(XMMATRIX& orthoMatrix)
{
    orthoMatrix = m_orthoMatrix;
    return;
}


void D3DClass::GetVideoCardInfo(char* cardName, int& memory)
{
    strcpy_s(cardName, 128, m_videoCardDescription);
    memory = m_videoCardMemory;
    return;
}
```

graphicsclass.cpp

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Filename: graphicsclass.cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "graphicsclass.h"
#include <d3d11_4.h>
#include <string>




GraphicsClass::GraphicsClass()
{
    m_Direct2D = 0;
    m_Direct3D = 0;
    m_Camera = 0;
    m_Model = 0;
    m_TextureShader = 0;
    user_textData=L"testtest";
    delta = 0;

}
clock_t begin_time = clock();

float framesPerSecond = 0;
int finalFrame = 0;


GraphicsClass::GraphicsClass(const GraphicsClass& other)
{
}


GraphicsClass::~GraphicsClass()
{
}


bool GraphicsClass::Initialize(int screenWidth, int screenHeight, HWND hwnd)
{

    bool result;


    // Create the Direct3D object.
    m_Direct3D = new D3DClass;
    if (!m_Direct3D)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Initialize the Direct3D object.
    result = m_Direct3D->Initialize(screenWidth, screenHeight, VSYNC_ENABLED, hwnd, FULL_SCREEN, SCREEN_DEPTH, SCREEN_NEAR);
    if (!result)
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, L"Could not initialize Direct3D.", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }
    m_Direct2D = new D2DClass;
    if (!m_Direct2D)
    {
        return false;
    }
    result = m_Direct2D->Initialize(screenWidth, screenHeight, VSYNC_ENABLED, hwnd, m_Direct3D->m_swapChain);
    if (!result)
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, L"Could not initialize the color shader object.", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }
    // Create the camera object.
    m_Camera = new CameraClass;
    if (!m_Camera)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Set the initial position of the camera.
    m_Camera->SetPosition(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);

    // Create the model object.
    m_Model = new ModelClass;
    if (!m_Model)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //PIXEL FORMAT SHOULD BE A8...
    char img[] = "xxxxx.tga";
    char img2[] = "stone01.tga";

    // Initialize the model object.
    result = m_Model->Initialize(m_Direct3D->GetDevice(), m_Direct3D->GetDeviceContext(), img);
    if (!result)
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, L"Could not initialize the model object.", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Create the texture shader object.
    m_TextureShader = new TextureShaderClass;
    if (!m_TextureShader)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Initialize the color shader object.
    result = m_TextureShader->Initialize(m_Direct3D->GetDevice(), hwnd);
    if (!result)
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, L"Could not initialize the color shader object.", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }



    return true;
}


void GraphicsClass::Shutdown()
{
    // Release the texture shader object.
    if (m_TextureShader)
    {
        m_TextureShader->Shutdown();
        delete m_TextureShader;
        m_TextureShader = 0;
    }

    // Release the model object.
    if (m_Model)
    {
        m_Model->Shutdown();
        delete m_Model;
        m_Model = 0;
    }

    // Release the camera object.
    if (m_Camera)
    {
        delete m_Camera;
        m_Camera = 0;
    }

    // Release the D3D object.
    if (m_Direct3D)
    {
        m_Direct3D->Shutdown();
        delete m_Direct3D;
        m_Direct3D = 0;
    }
    // Release the D2D object.
    if (m_Direct2D)
    {
        m_Direct2D->Shutdown();
        delete m_Direct2D;
        m_Direct2D = 0;
    }
    return;
}
ColorF cf[]{ ColorF::White,ColorF::Red,ColorF::Green,ColorF::Blue,ColorF::Yellow,ColorF::Orange,ColorF::Black,ColorF::Brown,ColorF::DarkRed,ColorF::DarkBlue,ColorF::DarkGreen,ColorF::Azure,ColorF::Aqua,ColorF::Purple,ColorF::DarkRed,ColorF::Cyan,ColorF::DarkCyan };
int arrayMax = (sizeof(cf[0])-1);
int RandIndex = 0;
bool GraphicsClass::Frame()
{

    framesPerSecond++;
        if (delta >= 1.0f) {
            finalFrame = framesPerSecond;
            framesPerSecond = delta = 0; begin_time = clock();
            RandIndex = rand() % arrayMax;
        }
        else {
            delta = float(clock() - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        }
    bool result;


    // Render the graphics scene.
    result = Render();
    if (!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool GraphicsClass::Render()
{
    XMMATRIX worldMatrix, viewMatrix, projectionMatrix;
    bool result;

    // Clear the buffers to begin the scene.
    m_Direct3D->BeginScene(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    // Generate the view matrix based on the camera's position.
    m_Camera->Render();

    // Get the world, view, and projection matrices from the camera and d3d objects.
    m_Direct3D->GetWorldMatrix(worldMatrix);
    m_Camera->GetViewMatrix(viewMatrix);
    m_Direct3D->GetProjectionMatrix(projectionMatrix);

    // Put the model vertex and index buffers on the graphics pipeline to prepare them for drawing.
    m_Model->Render(m_Direct3D->GetDeviceContext());

    // Render the model using the texture shader.
    result = m_TextureShader->Render(m_Direct3D->GetDeviceContext(), m_Model->GetIndexCount(), worldMatrix, viewMatrix, projectionMatrix, m_Model->GetTexture());
    if (!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // draw the text
    wstring FPS_STRING = to_wstring(finalFrame).append(L"Frames Per Second !");
    const wchar_t *test[] = { FPS_STRING.c_str() };

    m_Direct2D->RenderText(*test, L"Windows Command Prompt", 0, 0,cf[RandIndex]);
    const wchar_t *usr_txt[] = { user_textData.c_str() };

    m_Direct2D->RenderText(*usr_txt, L"Windows Command Prompt", 0, 70, ColorF::Red);

    // render stroked rounded Rectangle
    //m_Direct2D->RenderRectangle(XMFLOAT2(70, 30), XMFLOAT2(100, 100), XMFLOAT2(6, 6), 3.0f, ColorF::Red, true, false, true);

    // Present the rendered scene to the screen.
    m_Direct3D->EndScene();

    /*m_Direct2D->m_D2DMultithread->Leave();*/
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should analyze all HRESULT error code. There may be some hint in there. And you must add HRESULT checks where they're missing (like m_swapChain->Present). Also you can enable the debug layer in DXGI (use CreateDXGIFactory2 instead of CreateDXGIFactory) and check if all debug layers output something interesting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2ddebuglayer-portal https://walbourn.github.io/dxgi-debug-device/

Comment: I found it, there was no error but I made something weird in hwnd window. m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx( ..., screenW, screenH); That was something like zero for W and H. I forgot to pass params second time I think.

Comment: answer yourself if you're happy then

Answer (score 0):

Resolution should be set correctly:

```
screenWidth = 1366; //MY PC HAS THIS RESOLUTION, MANUALLY SET IT.
screenHeight = 768; //
```

m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, m_applicationName, m_applicationName,
    WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_POPUP,
    0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, NULL, NULL, m_hinstance, NULL);

I HAD A SECONDARY OWNER WINDOW THAT IS WHY I MISLEADED. STILL, I DO NOT KNOW THE REASON WHY INTEL RENDERS IT DESIRED SIZE example "199, 132" and NVIDIA DO NOT. NVIDIA WANTS TO RENDER SPECIFIC RESOLUTIONS LIKE 1024x768,1366x768 (tested them).